# SQL server crashes on first run

Tags: sql-server

I've just installed SQL Server on Ubuntu 22.04 and tried to run it using `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`. After choosing version and entering password I've recieved this message:

```
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Mon Jan 23 00:51:49 2023
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000001
         Signal: SIGSEGV - Segmentation fault (11)
 Signal Address: (nil)
    Signal Code: 0x00000001
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 00005590329275b2 <unknown>
                 0000559032926fd0 <unknown>
                 000055903295ba82 <unknown>
                 00005590328c655b <unknown>
                 00007fefb2a1a520 __sigaction+0x50
                 0000000000000000 <unknown>
                 00005590328d606e <unknown>
                 00005590328c2804 <unknown>
                 00005590328c2629 <unknown>
        Process: 59051 - sqlservr
         Thread: 59164 (application thread 0x1dc)
    Instance Id: 8fcc7c64-b2b3-4842-a871-f715ac0157f4
       Crash Id: f4da1afe-6482-4bf1-8f3e-5c69ac21565c
    Build stamp: d81e9b6de06534e649bd57dd609aa3050f5e380f361b7f8a80a80eeb71e7422c
   Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
     Processors: 8
   Total Memory: 8042852352 bytes
      Timestamp: Mon Jan 23 00:51:49 2023
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this should be posted at microsoft sql server forum

Comment: Have you reviewed Microsoft's Troubleshooting guide for MSSQL on Linux? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This is a later build than the supported one mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver16#supportedplatforms. Don't know if that could be the issue

Comment: An easy alternative to installing SQL Server on your Linux OS is to use the Docker containers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash

Comment: Since you're on Ubuntu 22.04, (currently) unsupported by SQL Server, you'll probably want to use one of the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) Docker images that themselves are built on top of Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: SQL Server has a text log file. Check this file to find the cause here: /var/opt/mssql/log